# AWS documentdb aggregate functionality seems not to run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have a mongodb-nodejs functionality which runs well on my local environment but doesn't run when deployed in aws documentdb.

Am using nodejs version v16.19.0, mongodb v4.14.0

Sample data in articles_collection

```
[
  {
      "_id": "6301276c5bd30c0b1481de60",
      "event_name": "read_article",
      "parameters": {
          "article_title": "Engineers explain cracks on Lotis towers",
          "article_id": 141193,
          "user_id": "547115761"
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "6301276c5bd30c0b1481de66",
      "event_name": "read_article",
      "parameters": {
          "article_title": "UK groom drowns in Packwach",
          "article_id": 141189,
          "user_id": "261225",
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "6301276e5bd30c0b1481de86",
      "event_name": "read_article",
      "parameters": {
          "article_title": "UK groom drowns in Packwach",
          "article_id": 141189,
          "user_id": "261225",
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "6301276e8738920b23c39e7e",
      "event_name": "read_article",
      "parameters": {
          "article_title": "Title 3",
          "article_id": 141171,
          "user_id": "286761",
      }
  },
]
```

```
const dbUrl = mongodb://<username>:<password>@<clustername>.cluster-csa8xeixiy9f.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, option);
```

```
const dbo = client.db('db_name');
const aggregateCursor = dbo.collection('articles_collection').aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        'parameters.article_id': 141189,
                    },
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            userId: '$parameters.user_id',
                        },
                        totalVisits: {
                            $sum: 1,
                        },
                    },
                },
                { $limit: 5 },
            ])
```

The above works well with local nodejs mongodb setup but fails with aws documentdb. Both forEach and toArray don't work at all and when I checked the logs, no errors where thrown either.

The find method seems to work well

```
dbo.collection('articles_collection').find().limit(5)
```

But the aggregate function doesn't. I tried to console log every step and seems the code just pauses when it gets to aggregation, causing the request to timeout and throw a 504 error.

What could I be doing wrong.
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: I don't see a reason why that aggregation wouldn't work with Amazon DocumentDB. Can you do an explain() in mongo shell to see the query plan?  `db.getCollection('articles_collection').explain('executionStats').aggregate([....])`

Comment: Thank you @MihaiA for the reply, will do that and revert and reply back